# Asp.Net MasterPage - Change WebContentForm body element - CssClass

Tags: master-pages, asp.net-3.5

What it's the easiest way to change the css class name of a WebContentForm that use a MasterPage ?

Example:

- MasterPage : `<body>...</body>`
- Index.aspx : I will like the rendered page to look like `<body class="myClass">...</body>`
- Other.aspx   : `<body>...</body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this workaround :

On MasterPage : `<body id="body" runat="server">`

On Index.cs : `((HtmlGenericControl)Page.Master.FindControl("body")).Attributes["class"] = "myClass";`

It's not really elegant, but it's work